# Add element in Handlebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have `handlebar.js` integration and I am populating a number of `dropdowns` using the template. Now I need to have a button which needs to add the same elements below. The code is like this

```
<div class='row'>
//my HTML goes here
<button>Add One more</button>
</div>
```

When I click on the `Add One more` button it needs to clone the div with class name row and needs to add it to the next line. How can I do this using Handlebars? Or I need to use jQuery here?

Comment: try this $('.row).prepend('<p>hola a todos</p>'); . This add at the begin of the .row element.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know `handlebars.js`, but with `jQuery` it'll be preety simple:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.row button', function() {
  var cloned = $(this).closest('.row').clone();
  $(this).closest('.row').parent().append(cloned);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    other stuff
    <button>add one</button>
  </div>
</div>
```